# how can I write thie for loop

Tags: shell

I try to write  my own shell script but I have some trouble.
What should I do?

```
./test_online.sh: line 47: host.booking.yh: command not found
```

```
host_tmp='host.booking'
host=$host_tmp'kpt' $host_tmp'yh' $host_tmp'mt'
for each_site in $host
    do
     #cd /home/toptrain/workspace/op_tools/ansible && ansible-playbook -i hosts/$each_site  test.yaml --extra-vars "branch=$branch" -v --tags "update" -v     
     echo $each_site
```

I what after for loop,it can output host.booking.kpt host.booking.yh host.booking.mt.but got this error

Comment: Format and explain question properly.

Comment: you need a closing `done` . Your assignment to `host=` will not work as intended. Maybe `host=( 1 2 3 )` gives you a hint. You will need to reference it as `${host[@}}`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> host=$host_tmp'kpt' $host_tmp'yh' $host_tmp'mt'
> ```

If you want to assign something containing spaces to a variable, you must quote those spaces, e. g.:

```
host="$host_tmp.kpt $host_tmp.yh $host_tmp.mt"
```